# How to separate value in datatable according to its primary key?

Tags: sql, vb.net, rdlc

I'm creating a report using RDLC and Visual Basic. I used 2 datatables to display information in the report which is one for main report(**DTT**) and another one for sub report(**TTT**). I have 2 dataset in RDLC, which are **TFDataset** and **TSDataset**. My report consist of 1 production order(**PO**) as primary key with multiple task in database. In a form, I created a Datagridview(**DGW**), for displaying data from database with checkboxes, and a ReportViewer, to display the report. The flow system is, the DGW shows list of PO, so user can tick multiple checkboxes from the DGW and print out those selected PO into a report. The selected PO are used to retrieve task using SQL and fill into the datatables. The PO are stored in DTT and task are stored in TTT. I used FOR EACH loop to run SQL for each check box value. DTT used for main report displays multiple PO correctly with proper page break but TTT seems to display a list of stacked task from other PO because the loop just added the task into the same datatable on each loop. Hence, the problem is how to separate the task according to its own PO?

```
Private Sub GenerateReport()

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("checkbox").Value)

            If isSelected Then

                Dim opt As QrCodeEncodingOptions = New QrCodeEncodingOptions
                opt.DisableECI = True
                opt.CharacterSet = "UTF-8"
                opt.Width = 250
                opt.Height = 250

                Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter()
                writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                writer.Options = opt

                Dim qr = New BarcodeWriter()
                qr.Options = opt
                qr.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                Dim Result = New Bitmap(qr.Write(imdata.Rows(row.Index)(1).ToString))

                Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream
                Result.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                connect.Open()
                Dim insert As New SqlCommand("update POTB set t_qrcd = @t_qrcd, t_pfno = @t_pfno, t_dtpr = @t_dtpr where t_pdno = '" + imdata.Rows(row.Index)(0).ToString + "'", connect)
                insert.Parameters.Clear()
                insert.Parameters.Add("@t_pfno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Upf
                insert.Parameters.Add("@t_qrcd", SqlDbType.Image).Value = stream.ToArray()
                insert.Parameters.Add("@t_dtpr", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Now
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Dim command As New SqlCommand("select t_pdno, t_item , t_dsca, t_qrdr, FORMAT(t_rdld,'dd/MM/yyyy') as t_rdld, t_opro, t_mark, t_qrcd, t_repr, t_pfno, FORMAT(t_dtpr,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') as t_dtpr FROM POTB                                           
                                               where t_pdno = '" + imdata.Rows(row.Index)(1).ToString + "'", connect)
                Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                adapter.Fill(DTT)
                Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("TFDataSet", DTT)

                Dim task As New SqlCommand("  select ttirou1022201.t_tano, ttirou0032201.t_dsca, ttirou1022201.t_opno from ttisfc0012201
                                              join ttcibd0012201 on ttcibd0012201.t_item = ttisfc0012201.t_mitm
                                              join ttirou1022201 on ttirou1022201.t_mitm = ttisfc0012201.t_mitm and ttirou1022201.t_opro = ttisfc0012201.t_opro
                                              join ttirou0032201 on ttirou0032201.t_tano = ttirou1022201.t_tano
                                              where ttisfc0012201.t_pdno = '" + imdata.Rows(row.Index)(1).ToString + "' and ttisfc0012201.t_mitm = '" + imdata.Rows(row.Index)(2).ToString + "'
                                              order by ttirou1022201.t_opno asc", connect)
                Dim taskap As New SqlDataAdapter(task)
                taskap.Fill(TTT)

                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
                connect.Close()

            End If

        Next

        list.Add(TTT)
        AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf SetSubDataSource

        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Yem.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Main Report PO ID as a Parameter to the sub report. This way each Instance of the sub report is filtered for its parent PO ID.
Take a look at this
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45c500d9-6de1-473e-b118-d023fc5ba988/ssrs-subreport-parameter-passing-issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought no one would answer this but I already solve it tho. I use **for** loop to print each report, which mean new MO header with its own task on every page, through form button and not through ReportViewer. This mean I separate the print and preview function. I use the form button for printing and the ReportViewer for preview.